# Getting new objects in the image

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to build a card recognition machine. The thing is the cards will be put on top of a cenario.

That being said i come for help on how can i compare to images, one is the empty background(cenario) and the other is the same cenario with a card on top of it.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

image1 = cv2.imread("gray_bk.png")
image2 = cv2.imread("gray_novo.png")

cv2.imwrite('LutGrey.png',gray_image)

novo = cv2.subtract(image1,image2) 
cv2.imwrite(file, novo)
```

this is my code so far, the problem with it, is that the return is a black image with the card in it (OK) but the colors in the card are all messed up, how do i execute the same operation without messing the colors ? And what would be the best way to "cut" the card into a new (smaller) image.

Comment: Provide the image as well. It's difficult for anyone to answer Image related question without having the image.

Comment: @saurabheights  the image link postimg.org/image/dz72s444t/

Comment: First, you should provide background Image as well as the final output you got. Next, you are using subtract, http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract . This method does a diff and then saturates the image, which is causing the distortion in color. Note distortion is not just because of saturation, but also because you are doing diff with a non-black image. Since, color(hue) is more related to ratio of R,G and B colors, the ratio will go off if you subtract R,G and B from a non-zero value.

Comment: IMHO, The answer provided by GpG is correct. You can also use the property that card has well defined red color. If you take HSV transform, you can use Hue channel to seperate Red color from background green color, however this will be less effective way for background with red colors. You can also use template matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with real images, I suggest the following:

- read colour images
- do some initial presmoothing
- substract grayscale images and threshold the result
- optionally do some morphological closing
- find the biggest region on the thresholded image with labelling
- get the bounding rectangle of the card area (for example cv's boundingRect) and extract this area from original colour image ¶

An alternative would be, in general a more robust approach, based on feature detection. Check this out for starter: 
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html. In this case, all possible card candidates must be known in advance.

If the card was just superimposed on the background image than this might work:

```
# read directly to float 
image1 = cv2.imread("gray_bk.png").astype(np.float) / 255
image2 = cv2.imread("gray_novo.png").astype(np.float) / 255

# substract and threshold
threshold = 0.1
binary_image = np.abs(np.mean(image2,2) - np.mean(image1,2)) > threshold
# get card area
y,x = np.where(binary_image)
# extract card from the image
card = image2[ y.min():y.max(), x.min():x.max(),:]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am really new in this area, my goal is to given an image like http://postimg.org/image/dz72s444t/ create a new image containing only the red card (so i send it to recognition). color will not be always the same so i need to subtract from background, any code would be a lot of help. thank you